# Unable to fetch child entity using @naturalId

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch the parent entity using @NaturalId column, it is giving me the below exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.example.demo.entities.Payment.referenceNo to java.lang.String
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393) ~[na:1.8.0_231]

The Entities are defined as

@Entity

```
public class Payment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    public String id;

    @NaturalId
    public String referenceNo;


@Entity
public class Sender {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;
    @Column
    private String senderName;
    @Column
    private String senderMobile;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PAYMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "referenceNo")
    @JsonBackReference
    public Payment payment;
```

In service class I am using `repo.findByReferenceNo(refNo);`

And if I use EnitityManager `Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Payment b = session.bySimpleNaturalId(Payment.class).load(refNo);`

I am getting below exception

> org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [public java.lang.String com.example.demo.entities.Payment.referenceNo] by reflection for persistent property [com.example.demo.entities.Payment#referenceNo] : 442056d5-2c2e-43be-91a9-f827c612e6d7
>       at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:419) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.generateHashCode(EntityUniqueKey.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.(EntityUniqueKey.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:738) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(AbstractRowReader.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4386) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:537) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2776) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2757) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2713) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2757) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$SimpleNaturalIdLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:3169) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       at com.example.demo.service.PaymentService.getTx(PaymentService.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
>       at com.example.demo.service.PaymentService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$64c00a42.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at com.example.demo.service.PaymentService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c6225a7.getTx() ~[classes/:na]
>       at com.example.demo.controller.PaymentController.searchTx(PaymentController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.example.demo.entities.Payment.referenceNo to java.lang.String
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>       at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
>       ... 94 common frames omitted

2020-03-18 15:25:42.736 ERROR 14964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [public java.lang.String com.example.demo.entities.Payment.referenceNo] by reflection for persistent property [com.example.demo.entities.Payment#referenceNo] : 442056d5-2c2e-43be-91a9-f827c612e6d7] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.example.demo.entities.Payment.referenceNo to java.lang.String
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:419) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.generateHashCode(EntityUniqueKey.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.(EntityUniqueKey.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:738) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(AbstractRowReader.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4386) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:537) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2776) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2757) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2713) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2757) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$SimpleNaturalIdLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:3169) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at com.example.demo.service.PaymentService.getTx(PaymentService.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.service.PaymentService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$64c00a42.invoke()

Comment: Why do you have public fields in your entities? Make them private and add getters and setters

Comment: Simon Martinelli  I am using @Data of Lambok for getters and setters.
Can we Fetch using natural id column? When i try to debug it is using id column to fetch child records

Comment: sure you can. Can you please post the whole stacktrace?